# Как при переходе из фрагмента в фрагмент выводить Loading animation?

Tags: android, android-fragment, xamarin, android-animation, loading

Нахожусь в фрагменте, для отображения нового фрагмента использую код:

```
// выводим фрагмент и сохраняем состояние окна для кнопки возврата
CatalogFragment catalogFragment = new CatalogFragment();
var fragmentManager = Activity.SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
fragmentManager.Replace(Resource.Id.flContent, (SupportFragment)catalogFragment);
fragmentManager.AddToBackStack(null);
fragmentManager.Commit();
```

Как вывести loading animation (т.е. визуальное представление загрузки: "animated circle" или gif'ку) пока фрагмент не загрузился?